# Non differentiability of self-similar processes

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation

**Proposition.**(Non differentiability of self-similar processes) Suppose $(X_t)$ is H-self-similar with stationary increments for some $H\in (0,1)$. Then for every fixed $t_0$,
$$\limsup_{t\downarrow t_0}\frac{\lvert X_t-X_{t_0}\rvert}{t-t_0}=\infty,$$
i.e sample paths of H-self-similar processes are nowhere differentiable with probability $1$.

**Proof.** Without loss of generality we choose $t_0=0$. Let $\{t_n\}$ be a sequence such that $t_n\downarrow 0$. Then, by H-self-similarity, $X_0=0$ a.s. Let $x>0$ be a real number. Observe that the event
$$\bigg\{\sup_{0\le s\le t_{n+1}}\frac{\lvert X_s\rvert}{s}>x\bigg\}\subseteq\bigg\{\sup_{0\le s\le t_{n}}\frac{\lvert X_s\rvert}{s}>x\bigg\},$$ then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\lim_n\sup_{0\le s \le t_n}\frac{\lvert X_s\rvert}{s}>x\bigg\} = &\lim_n\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\sup_{0\le s \le t_n}\frac{\lvert X_s\rvert}{s}>x\bigg\}\\
= &\limsup_n\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\sup_{0\le s \le t_n}\frac{\lvert X_s\rvert}{s}>x\bigg\}\\
\ge & \limsup_n\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\frac{\lvert X_{t_n}\rvert}{t_n}>x\bigg\}\\
= & \limsup_n\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\lvert X_1\rvert >xt_n^{1-H}\bigg\}\\
\color{red}{=} & \mathbb{P}\big\{\lvert X_1\rvert>0\big\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

> **Question** I did not understand the inequality in red. Could someone explain it to me? Thanks.

I observed that the events sequence
$$\bigg\{\lvert X_1\rvert> xt_n^{1-H}\bigg\}\subseteq \bigg\{\lvert X_1\rvert> xt_{n+1}^{1-H}\bigg\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that since $H < 1$ and $t_n \downarrow 0$ one has that
$$\{|X_1| > 0\} = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \{|X_1| > xt_n^{1-H}\}$$
so that (since the sets in the intersection on the right hand side are decreasing in $n$) by elementary properties of probability measures
$$\mathbb{P}(\{|X_1| > 0\}) = \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{n \geq 1} \{|X_1| > xt_n^{1-H}\}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\{|X_1| > xt_n^{1-H}\}).$$